# how can I extract all the tables from a pdf using tabula library in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdftotext, tabula, pdf-to-html

Can anyone suggest a way to extract all the tables with the filled up values inside them from a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

[Tabula PDF](https://tabula.technology/) provides a way to extract the table information in the pdf. It has its [python](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) version too.